# Use lme() within the dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, nlme

**Question**

Hello,
I would like to use the function lme() from the nlme package inside the pipe.

**Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nlme)

df <- tribble( 
  ~id_pat,  ~diff,
  1,          -15, 
  2,         NA,
  3,         -25.2,
  4,          46.2,
  1,         16.4,
  2,         -12,
  3,         9, 
  4,         14
)
```

**Code**

This works:

```
lme(diff ~ 1, random = ~1 |
      id_pat, na.action = na.omit, data = df)
```

This doesn't work:

```
df %>%
   lme(diff ~ 1, random = ~1 |
       id_pat, na.action = na.omit)
```

I've tried several solutions, none of them work:

```
# With pull
df %>%
  lme(pull(.x["diff"]) ~1, random = ~1 |
      pull(.x["id_pat"]), na.action = na.omit))

# With eval & subtitue
b <- df["id_pat"]
df %>%
  lme(eval(substitute(j ~ 1, list(j = as.name("diff")))), random = ~1 |
      b, na.action = na.omit, data = df_time_point_as_col_pf)

# With paste0
b <- df["id_pat"]
df_time_point_as_col %>% 
  lme(paste0(diff_avt_dd_pdt_dv, "~1"), random = ~1 |
      b, na.action = na.omit
      )

# With broom
library(broom)
df %>%
  broom::tidy(lme(pull(.x["diff"]) ~1, random = ~1 |
                  pull(.x["id_pat"]), na.action = na.omit))

# With broom.mixed
library(broom.mixed)
df %>%
  broom.mixed::tidy(lme(pull(.x["diff"]) ~1, random = ~1 |
                        pull(.x["id_pat"]), na.action = na.omit))
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try `df %>% lme(diff ~ 1, random = ~1 | id_pat, na.action = na.omit, data=.)`.  You can use `.` to move the object on the left of the pipe from its default position of "first argument of the function on the right of the pipe.  It's all in the online doc.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the data with `.`

```
library(dplyr)
library(nlme)

df %>% 
  lme(diff ~ 1, random = ~1 |
        id_pat, na.action = na.omit, data = .)

#Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#  Data: . 
#  Log-restricted-likelihood: -28.5764
#  Fixed: diff ~ 1 
#(Intercept) 
#   4.398488 

#Random effects:
# Formula: ~1 | id_pat
#        (Intercept) Residual
#StdDev:    9.773561 22.46122

#Number of Observations: 7
#Number of Groups: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.` for the data as @RonakShah suggests is fine.  You can also name the arguments provided to make sure that `data` is the first *unspecified* argument in the argument list

```r
df %>% lme(fixed = diff ~ 1, random = ~1|id_pat, na.action = na.omit)
```

i.e. since `args(lme)` is

```
function (fixed, data = sys.frame(sys.parent()), random, correlation = NULL, 
    weights = NULL, subset, method = c("REML", "ML"), na.action = na.fail, 
    control = list(), contrasts = NULL, keep.data = TRUE)
```

and we have explicitly specified `fixed`, the piped argument will be identified as `data`.